# match.call with default arguments

Tags: r

As part of a function, I want to output a list of all the arguments and their values, including the default values. For example, a function with these arguments:

```
foo <- function(x=NULL,y=NULL,z=2) {
  #formals()
  #as.list(match.call())[-1]
  #some other function?....
}
```

To give output as such:

```
> foo(x=4)

$x
[1] 4

$y
NULL

$z
[1] 2
```

`formals` does not update to give the values argument values when the function is called. `match.call` does, but does not provide the defaults of the arguments. Is there another function out there that will provide the output as I want?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Hopefully, this doesn't lead to dragons.

```
foo <- function(x=NULL,y=NULL,z=2) {
  mget(names(formals()),sys.frame(sys.nframe()))

}

foo(x=4)

$x
[1] 4

$y
NULL

$z
[1] 2

print(foo(x=4))

$x
[1] 4

$y
NULL

$z
[1] 2
```

Comment: If you want to make a function out of this, I guess `mget(names(formals(sys.function(sys.parent()))), sys.frame(sys.nframe() - 1L))` (subtracting one to get to the "previous" frame of the function where your helper is called)

Comment: Ouf.... dragons indeed. Beware of lazy evaluation here... I tried passing `bar(l = foo())` and due to lazy eval, `foo()` could be evaluated only much later (e.g. several frames deeper within `bar()`). So be sure to evaluate `foo()` explicitly in the correct frame.

Answer (score 12):

you can use a mix of the 2 , `match.call` and `formals`

```
foo <- function(x=NULL,y=NULL,z=2)
{
  ll <- as.list(match.call())[-1]     ## 
  myfor <- formals(foo)               ## formals with default arguments
  for ( v in names(myfor)){
             if (!(v %in% names(ll)))
                ll <- append(ll,myfor[v])  ## if arg is missing I add it
             }
  ll
}
```

For example :

```
  foo(y=2)
$y
[1] 2

$x
NULL

$z
[1] 2

> foo(y=2,x=1)
$x
[1] 1

$y
[1] 2

$z
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is an attempt to wrap this logic in a reusable function to drop in instead of `match.call`:

```
match.call.defaults <- function(...) {
  call <- evalq(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE), parent.frame(1))
  formals <- evalq(formals(), parent.frame(1))

  for(i in setdiff(names(formals), names(call)))
    call[i] <- list( formals[[i]] )


  match.call(sys.function(sys.parent()), call)
}
```

It looks like it works:

```
foo <- function(x=NULL,y=NULL,z=2,...) {
  match.call.defaults()
}


> foo(nugan='hand', x=4)
foo(x = 4, y = NULL, z = 2, ... = pairlist(nugan = "hand"))
```

Comment: Also I've added this function to the stackoverflow package.

Comment: This function works nicely but I noticed one limitation that becomes an issue for me and that I would like to address: When calling the foo function not as in your example with specific parameter assignments but instead with variables, the name of the variable is stored in the result and not the actual parameter value.

x_test = 4
foo(x=x_test)
-> foo(x = x_test, y = NULL, z = 2, ... = )

Is there any way to translate variable assignments for simple types to their actual value in this context? I guess deparse(substitute()) somewhere but I didnt figure it out yet

Comment: @ChristianArnold - in other R code I have seen, they would typically replace the foo() in the resulting expression with list() and then evaluate it.

Answer (score 5):

```
 foo <- function(x=NULL,y=NULL,z=2) {
   X <- list(x,y,z); names(X) <- names(formals()); X
 }
 z <- foo(4)
 z
#------
$x
[1] 4

$y
NULL

$z
[1] 4
```

Comment: Umm, there seems to be a typo, I guess it should be `x <- list(x,y,z)`. If you create the list manually, why don't you just name the entries directly?

Comment: Fixed the typo. The question should be directed to the OP.