# Regular Expression Select Comma But Not In Between Parentheses

Tags: regex, r, string

I'm looking to create a function in R that loads the defaults of a given function. To do this, I'm using the `args` argument on a function and looking to break it down to the defaulted arguments of the function and load those into the global environment. This takes a bit of regular expressions and have bumped into this that I'm having difficulty addressing.

Here is a sample function:

```
myFunc <- function(a = 1, b = "hello world", c = c("Hello", "World")) {}
```

I've gotten it down to this point using my own functions:

```
x <- "a = 1, b = \"hello world\", c = c(\"Hello\", \"World\")"
```

However, where I am struggling is on splitting the function arguments up. I wanted to split on a comma, but if you have a function argument that has a comma within the default (like the `c` argument does), then that causes issues. What I'm thinking is if there is a way to call a regular expression that matches a comma, but not a comma this in between two parentheses, then I could use `strsplit` with that expression to get what I want.

My attempt to match the case of a comma between two parentheses looks like this:

```
\\(.*,.*\\)
```

Now, I've looked into how to do what I described above and it seems like a negative look ahead may be what I need, so I've attempted to do something like this.

```
splitx <- strsplit(x, "(?!\\(.*,.*\\)(,)")
```

But R tells me it is an illegal regular expression. If I set `perl = TRUE` in the argument, it just returns the same string. Any help here would be greatly appreciated and I hope I've been clear!

Comment: Matching something outside another thing is easy with PCRE regex - [`strsplit(x, "\\([^)]+\\)(*SKIP)(*F)|,", perl=TRUE)`](http://ideone.com/Cw6U5n). However, make sure you are not heading a blind alley with regexps here.

Comment: Your question has much wider scope than the issue you're facing. Would I be short-cutting if I suggest that `match.call()` might get you to your goal faster?

Comment: Some searching will find more details, but you could start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397364/match-call-with-default-arguments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to try and answer your underlying question.

The function `formals()` returns a pairlist of the formal arguments of a function. You can use the result of `formals()` by testing for `is.symbol()` and `is.null()`.  Anything that isn't a symbol and isn't null either, contains a default value.

For example:

```
get_default_args <- function(fun){
  x <- formals(fun)
  w <- sapply(x, function(x)!is.symbol(x) && !is.null(x))
  x[w]
}
```

Try it on `lm()`:

```
get_default_args(lm)
$method
[1] "qr"

$model
[1] TRUE

$x
[1] FALSE

$y
[1] FALSE

$qr
[1] TRUE

$singular.ok
[1] TRUE
```

Try it on your function:

```
myFunc <- function(a = 1, b = "hello world", c = c("Hello", "World")) {}
get_default_args(myFunc)
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] "hello world"

$c
c("Hello", "World")
```

---

Note that the comments suggests using `match.call()`. This may or may not work for you, but `match.call()` evaluates the argument *in the environment of the function after being called*, whereas `formals()` evaluates the language object itself. Therefore you don't need to call the function at all when using `formals()`.

Comment: Pretty cool stuff, and that `formals()` argument is very useful. Thanks for this!

Comment: My support of `match.call()` perhaps misunderstands the use-case here. This answer (`formals()`) correctly handles what I now think OP is trying to achieve and while it gets an upvote from me, the official question is formally regarding the regex, so I've answered to that below.

Comment: Yeah, no fret. Andrie was just going above the question to my more overarching goal.

Comment: I like this answer, I do, but in the interest of the SO search results, I don't think it should be the accepted answer as it doesn't address the question as stated.

Comment: Andrie, +1, but you may need to adjust the detection mechanism.  I typically use something like `!(is.name(x) && !nzchar(as.character(x)))`.  Check out `get_default_args(function(x, y=x, b=NULL))`.  That function has two default args.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think this is the right approach (use `match.call()` to extract arguments as they were passed), a matching regex is

```
x <- "a = 1, b = \"hello world\", c = c(\"Hello\", \"World\")"
strsplit(x, ",(?![^()]*\\))", perl=TRUE)

#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a = 1"                        " b = \"hello world\""         " c = c(\"Hello\", \"World\")"
```

Comment: I believe the problem with `match.call` in my case is that it needs to be used within the function, whereas I want to use this outside the function.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood your goal there. `formals()` is the approach you probably want, but your question as stated is still about the regex, hence this answer.